# categorical variables with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, types

When loading a csv file that looks like this

```
0 1 male 3 4 5 6
1 0 female 6 7 8 9
.....
```

is it possible to automatically convert the third column to integers, for example 0 for male and 1 for female?

Comment: yes, it is, how are you loading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) accepts an argument named `converters`. This can be used to apply functions to particular columns as a file is read in. `converters` should be passed in as a dictionary of the following form:

```
{column_index: function_to_apply}
```

You could use this to apply a function to the third column. All you need to do is set the function to get a value from a dictionary `d` which maps `"male"` to `0` and `"female"` to `1`:

```
>>> d = {"male": 0, "female": 1}
>>> pd.read_csv(file.csv, converters={2: d.get})
...
0 1 0 3 4 5 6
1 0 1 6 7 8 9
...
```